# WPF redirect to a page with POST request body

Tags: c#, wpf, post

I have a simple WPF application with a button. When I click the button, I want to open the URL in the default browser and pass some data through POST body.
I know how to do that with GET, but what I want is using POST method.

Example:

```cs
Uri uri = new Uri("http://mypage.com");
string data = somedata;
    
// what to do next to redirect with POST method?
```

Note: I want to open the page in the user's default browser but not the .NET browser control.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Process.Start(uri); it will detect the protocol  (http) and open the default app for that protocol which will be your browser.

But that will result in a GET. Maby its better to use a WebRequest or RestAPI.

Comment: I tried that, but what i want is POST request, any solution with POST?